# Php - How to return the result of foreach input?

Tags: php, forms, input, foreach, isset

I have one form for multiple input entries.

I would like loop through it to grab the data using the foreach function and return the result.

But somehow it keep failing because $_POST

```
<?php
$age = array(
    "Peter"=> '35f',
    "Ben"=> '37f', 
    "Joe"=> '43f'
);

foreach( $age as $x => $x_value ) {
    (isset($_POST['$x_value'])) ? $y = $_POST['$x_value'] : '';

    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value . ", Input=" . $y;
    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

The form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="35f" value="6d583"/>
    <input name="37f" value="2ds43"/>
    <input name="43f" value="5533d"/>
    <input name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Expected result :

```
Key=Peter, Value=35f, Input=6d583
Key=Ben, Value=37f, Input=2ds43
Key=Joe, Value=43f, Input=5533d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need single quotes here:

```
$y = isset($_POST[$x_value]) ? $_POST[$x_value] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_value` inside brackets without '' because it's a variable not an string

```php
<?php (isset($_POST[$x_value])) ? $y = $_POST[$x_value] : '';
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was so distracted  :)